# AngularJS How do I keep a select which is inside a dropdown open

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this peace of bootstrap code, it is a dropdown and inside the dropdown I have two selects which are generated by an array which is the model `range_price` how do I keep the selects showing once is clicked?

Thank you.

```
<div class="button-group col-md-1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle"
          data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret">
      </span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <label>Min-Price</label>
        <select ng-model="range_price" ng-options="range as range for range in range_price"></select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Max-Price</label>
        <select ng-model="range_price" ng-options="range as range for range in range_price"></select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps, added this directive "dropdown-with-select" to 'ul' tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Demo App</title>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
</head>
<body ng-app="demo">
<div class="container" ng-controller="demoController">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="button-group col-md-1">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
     <span class="caret"></span></button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdown-with-select>
    <li>
     <label>Min-Price</label>
     <select ng-model="min_price" ng-options="range as range for range in range_price">
      <option value="">- Select Price -</option>
     </select>
    </li>
    <li>
     <label>Max-Price</label>
     <select ng-model="max_price" ng-options="range as range for range in range_price">
      <option value="">- Select Price -</option>
     </select>
    </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <h3>Selected Min Price : {{min_price}}</h3>
   <h3>Selected Max Price : {{max_price}}</h3>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('demo',[])
  .controller('demoController',['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.min_price=null;
 $scope.max_price=null;
 $scope.range_price=[100,200,300,400];
  }])
  .directive('dropdownWithSelect',[function(){
 return {
  restrict:"A",
  link:function(scope,element,attrs){
   angular.element(element).click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
   });
  }  
 }
  }]);
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!